# .htaccess склеиваем дубли страниц

Tags: редирект, .htaccess, joomla

Доброго дня всем читающим! :)

У меня на сайте имеют место быть дубли страниц по следующим адресам:
site.ru/category1.html  = site.ru/category1  = site.ru/category1/  мне нужно оставить только первый вариант. 
это же справедливо и к материалам site.ru/category1/material1.html site.ru/category1/material1 = site.ru/category1/material1/

Как поступить правильней, склеить эти страницы через .htacces или может быть исключить существование этих дублирующих страниц, чтобы отдавали 404 код.
использую joomla 2.5

Очень признателен за ответы

Comment: Правильнее всего выводить на страницы только один вариант URI, чем в разных местах делать их разными.

Answer (score 1):

Один уникальный контент == один url.

Я думаю, что гуглу не очень понравиться, если он найдет одно и тоже содержимое на разных страницах сайта.

Т.е. лучше оставить какой-то один вариант, а по остальным отдавать 404.

Comment: Спасибо, Artem Ryzhov, мне тоже близка эта мысль. Сложно представить. как это можно реализовать в joomla 2.5 + k2
Может быть можно в robots закрыть все страницы, не содержащие html (КАК?)) а потом открыть несколько нужных, в адресе которых нет html

Comment: Честно говоря, ни разу не использовал joomla, и понятия не имею как оно там настраивается :( 

http://joomclub.net/blog/seo/26.html

Вот в этой статье (1-й пункт) предлагают установить какой-то плагин, и настроить там маршрутизацию.

Думаю что настройка через админку будет наиболее правильное решение, чем править .htaccess. Все-таки это ж cms :)

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectMatch /([a-z0-9-_\/]+) /$1.html`

это добавить в `htaccess`

Comment: Циклическая переадресация получается, если эту строку добавить